# How do I detect what type a variable is in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

A parameter is being set and I need to check if it is a number or not.  If not, I need to change its value to 1.

```
<c:if test="${param.pageOffset TEST HERE}">
    <c:set target="param" property="pageOffset" value="1" />
</c:if>
```

I'm very new to jsp so I could be completely on the wrong track.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not the job of a JSP to validate request parameters. Do that in your action/servlet, and store the appropriate pageOffset value as a request attribute.

Comment: You're right, I've looked into it more and found the Java controller class.  I'll change it there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible it's better to do this type of processing in your Java code, and send the result ready-made to the JSP.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this using pure JSTL but if you decide to keep this operation in the JSP you could just use a [scriptlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html)

Answer (score 0):

Automatic type *coercion* is the *main* feature of `EL/JSTL`. It means they define appropriate conversions and default values.

You may try `<c:catch>` JSTL tag to test whether a value is *numeric* or not.

```
<c:set var="num" value="1"/>
<c:catch var="coerError">
   <c:set value="num" value="${num*1}" />
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${not empty coerError}">

</c:if>
```